# Identifying a build as being due to a dependent project reference

Tags: msbuild

In MSBuild is there a property, or some other mechanism, that indicates that the current project is being built because it was a referenced by another project?

Comment: Depends on what your definition of 'being built' is. When project A has a reference to project B, msbuild actually gets invoked multiple times on project B, with different targets. For the actual Build target there's no way to distinguish it from a normal build (at least none that I know of, when using standard VS generated project files: looking at diagnostic build output everything is exactly the same). For the other targets (GetNativeManifest, GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems) you could probably assume they only get called when the project is being built because it's referenced.

Comment: @stijn Thanks, it was indeed the Build target I was after, but good to know. If you add that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @stijn Out of interest. Can you cause an additional property to be passed to dependent projects without passing that same property into the entry project? (by, for example, adding some metadata to a certain item)

Comment: Doesn't look like it, just Configuration and Platform are passed but there is no extension point to hook into. You can override which target gets built (so e.g. instead of the default one you could have it build 'MyBuild' or so). Or you could override the ResolveProjectReferences target completely in the master project. But none of those solutions are exactly ideal. To make things worse, this is with command line builds only. I didn't check but building in VS is different I think. Don't have time now but I'll verify tomorrow and prepare an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking around a bit this does not seem possible using built-in functionaility. From one point of view this makes sense: why would a project have to know whether it's built directly by the user vs being built as a dependency? Possibly the MSBuild team followed that logic as well: there are quite a lot of extensions points in MSBuild but not for doing this.

Two problems: the code for building the dependent projects is just using the MSBuild Task and does not provide a way to pass properties. But even if it did, it would only work when building from the command line, not in VS, so it's not a 'complete' solution. Here's a snippet taken from the ResolveProjectReferences which builds the dependent projects:

```
<!--
    Build referenced projects when building from the command line.
    -->
<MSBuild
    Projects="@(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent)"
    Targets="%(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent.Targets)"
    BuildInParallel="$(BuildInParallel)"
    Properties="%(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent.SetConfiguration); %(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent.SetPlatform)"
    Condition="'%(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent.BuildReference)' == 'true' and '@(ProjectReferenceWithConfiguration)' != '' and '$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' != 'true' and '$(BuildProjectReferences)' == 'true' and '@(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent)' != ''"
    ContinueOnError="$(ContinueOnError)"
    RemoveProperties="%(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent.GlobalPropertiesToRemove)">
  ...
</MSBuild>
```

So, no way to add properties here. Though as you figured you can remove properties by setting a ProjectReference's GlobalPropertiesToRemove; depending on what you're after this could be valueable.

For the rest there aren't many options left; you can specify the target used: _MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent.Targets gets set to $(ProjectReferenceBuildTargets) so you can override the target called but then you'd need all your projects which could possibly be dependent projects to declare a custom target (which would in turn call the Build target as well in order not to break things). Doable, but not nice, and not a direct answer to the question. Same goes for other solutions: you could just override the whole ResolveProjectReferences target (for any project which can have dependent projects) by copying it and adding a property in the snippet shown above.

But as said (and as shown in the Condition in the above snippet): none of these possible solutions would apply when building in VS. I don't know exactly why or how that works, but if A depends on B and you build A in VS and it sees B is out of date it just fires up a build for it before even building A and I don't know of any standard way to interact with that.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @stijn's answer, I've discovered that you can also *prevent* a property from being passed to dependent projects.

For example, you can prevent Web Project dependencies from building with the top level project by updating their `<ProjectReference>` to include `<GlobalPropertiesToRemove>DeployOnBuild</GlobalPropertiesToRemove>`. Or, to do it automatically based on another property:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(DisableProjectReferenceDeployOnBuild)'=='true'">
  <BeforeResolveReferences>
    $(BeforeResolveReferences);
    DisableProjectReferenceDeployOnBuild
  </BeforeResolveReferences>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="DisableProjectReferenceDeployOnBuild">
  <ItemGroup>
    <_ProjectReferencesTmp Include="@(ProjectReferences)" />
    <ProjectReferences Remove="@(ProjectReferences)" />
    <ProjectReferences Include="@(_ProjectReferencesTmp)">
      <GlobalPropertiesToRemove>%(GlobalPropertiesToRemove);DeployOnBuild</GlobalPropertiesToRemove>
    </ProjectReferences>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

(I won't mark this as the answer since it doesn't directly answer the question I asked)

Comment: Did you test this? Why do you use `ProjectReferences` instead of `ProjectReference`?

Answer (score 1):

With modern versions of visualstudio/.net SDK, you can do this in your `Directory.Build.targets` to apply this to all (as this requires participation from the project which is depending on other projects):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IsBuildDueToProjectReference Condition=" '$(IsBuildDueToProjectReference)' == '' ">false</IsBuildDueToProjectReference>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target AfterTargets="AssignProjectConfiguration" Name="SetIsBuildDueToProjectReferenceOnProjectReferences">
    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReferenceWithConfiguration>
        <AdditionalProperties>%(ProjectReferenceWithConfiguration.AdditionalProperties);IsBuildDueToProjectReference=true</AdditionalProperties>
      </ProjectReferenceWithConfiguration>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

This works because targets build items from `ProjectReferenceWithConfiguration`. So you can treat that item as if it is passed as the `Projects` parameter of the [MSBuild Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-task?view=vs-2022#pass-properties-to-projects) because its metadata will be carried along.

To see the effect, you can put something like the following in each of your project files:

```xml
<Target AfterTargets="Build" Name="PrintInfo">
  <Warning Text="IsBuildDueToProjectReference=$(IsBuildDueToProjectReference)"/>
</Target>
```

For example, if I build `ConsoleApp1.csproj` which has a dependency on `ClassLibrary1.csproj`, I get:

```
C:\Users\ohnob\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj(10,5): warning : IsBuildDueToProjectReference=true
C:\Users\ohnob\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj(15,5): warning : IsBuildDueToProjectReference=false
```

And if I build `ClassLibrary.csproj` direct, I get:

```
C:\Users\ohnob\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj(10,5): warning : IsBuildDueToProjectReference=false
```